# get real path from URI of type data.getData() file:///storage/emulated/0/LenovoReaper/did

Tags: android, uri

My application going to `ANR` when I choose file and try to get its real path. my

```
 public static String getRealPathFromUri(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

but same thing works fine if I choose any media file like image.

Works fine for `data.getData() = content://media/external/images/media/22555 real path`

real path is `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/20150406_210053.jpg`

for non media file it goes to `ANR`

```
data.getData() file:///storage/emulated/0/LenovoReaper/did
```

nothing is returned and Application goes to `ANR`. Could some one suggest how to get real path of such `URI` or should I just remove `file://` from the `data.getData()`

Answer (score 3):

For opening the gallery use this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction("android.intent.action.PICK");
                        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

In onActivityResult :

```
if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && data != null && data.getData() != null) {  
   String absolutePath = "file://" + getPath(this,data.getData());  
            
        }
```

And the getPath function:

```
public static String getPath( Context context, Uri uri ) {
    String result = null;
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver( ).query( uri, proj, null, null, null );
    if(cursor != null){
        if ( cursor.moveToFirst( ) ) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( proj[0] );
            result = cursor.getString( column_index );
        }
        cursor.close( );
    }
    if(result == null) {
        result = "Not found";
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: file://"+result);
    return result;
}
```

**It will give you the absolute path of the image like "file:///storage/emulated/0/LenovoReaper/did"**

Comment: Nice method `getPath()` that returns string real path from uri .tested and works and you got one more vote from me .Thanks I would like just notify you that `OnActivityResult()` is deprecated and no more used . there is a new approach `ActivityResultLauncher<Uri>`

Answer (score 0):

> Could some one suggest how to get real path of such URI

There is no "real path" other than the `Uri` itself.

> should I just remove file:// from the data.getData()

That will not do you any good.

[A `Uri` is not a `File`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html). There is no requirement for any `Uri` to have to point to a file that you can access. If you want to get access to the data represented by the `Uri`, use methods on `ContentResolver`, such as `openInputStream()`.